# simple date wise sorting array not working

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, date

Here this is my array.(This array is for example)

```
Array(
        [0] => Array
            (
                [amt] => 50.00
                [transaction_date] => 2015-01-01
            )  
        [1] => Array
            (
                [amt] => 0.00
                [transaction_date] => 2015-02-01
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [amt] => 60.00
                [transaction_date] => 2015-01-01
            )
    )
```

I am trying to sort or grouping to array according to date.transaction date should be one means no duplicate entry of transaction in array.I want this array should also sort by the date.Means 2015-01-01 should at first and 2015-02-01 next to 2015-01-01 and so on if dates are available.

I want new array as follows

```
Array(
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [amt] => 110.00
                    [transaction_date] => 2015-01-01
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [amt] => 0.00
                    [transaction_date] => 2015-02-01
                )            

        )
```

2015-01-01 this date appears 2 times in array with 2 different amount amount should added as per repetition. amount should be 110

I have tried

```
$result = array();
foreach ($output as $key => $value) {
    $hash = $value['transaction_date'];
    if (isset($result[$hash])) {
        $result[$hash]['amt'] += $value['amt'];
        $result[$hash]['transaction_date'] = $value['transaction_date'];
    } else {
        $result[$hash]['amt'] = $value['amt'];
        $result[$hash]['transaction_date'] = $value['transaction_date'];
    }
}
print_r(array_values($result));
```

this is my actual json encoded result

```
{"2015-07-18":{"amt":50,"transaction_date":"2015-07-18"},"2015-05-28":{"amt":"450.00","transaction_date":"2015-05-28"},"2015-06-02":{"amt":"200.00","transaction_date":"2015-06-02"},"2015-06-18":{"amt":"12610.00","transaction_date":"2015-06-18"},"2015-06-23":{"amt":"0.00","transaction_date":"2015-06-23"},"2015-06-24":{"amt":"603.00","transaction_date":"2015-06-24"},"2015-07-14":{"amt":"0.00","transaction_date":"2015-07-14"},"2015-07-16":{"amt":"0.00","transaction_date":"2015-07-16"},"2015-07-17":{"amt":"0.00","transaction_date":"2015-07-17"}}
```

you can check this arrray in this link
http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Answer (score 0):

Try simply using `usort` as

```
$result = array();
foreach ($output as $key => $value) {
    $hash = $value['transaction_date'];
    if (isset($result[$hash])) {
        $result[$hash]['amt'] += $value['amt'];
        $result[$hash]['transaction_date'] = $value['transaction_date'];
    } else {
        $result[$hash]['amt'] = $value['amt'];
        $result[$hash]['transaction_date'] = $value['transaction_date'];
    }
}

uasort(array_values($result),function($a,$b){
     return $a['transaction_date'] - $b['transaction_date'];
});
print_r(array_values($result));
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](https://eval.in/415847)

Comment: Only sorting the values won't combine them.

Comment: Op has already have that code @Rizier123. Even though I've updated my answer